# How to get particular Column value Row SQL server

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am using SQl server. i have Imported Excel Sheet to SQL server. i have 1500 Rows  Sql server Like . i have three Columns SQL server. like this

```
  AMOUNT    EMPLOYEE           DEDUCTION
    277.6   Addison, Franklin   401K %
    41.31   Addison, Franklin   401K Loan 1
    125.04  Addison, Franklin   Dental PDO
    268.47  Addison, Franklin   Plat PPO
    119.23  Akusobi, Kelechi    401K %
    446.43  Aldridge, John      401K %
    381.63  Alexander, Kathryn  401K %
    128.73  Alexander, Kathryn  Gold PPO
    423.23  Aliabadi, Amir      401K %
    59.16   Aliabadi, Amir     Dental Max
    179.95  Aliabadi, Amir     Plat PPO
    255.77  Allan, Matthew      401K %
    45.2    Allan, Matthew      Dental PDO
    26.93   Allan, Matthew  FSA Health
```

in this table  I have three column  AMOUNT,EMPLOYEE,DEDUCTIOn. want to select which employee have  401k% . how to  select which Employee have  401k% for this table ? how can i select ? please any one Guide me

Comment: select * from #Table1 where DEDUCTION ='401K %'

Comment: This is an extreamly basic sql - I would suggest to read about `select` in any sql tutorial.

Comment: @Chanukya  its Working.how To check with two value. Now i want check two value  401k% and Dental PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from #Table1 where DEDUCTION  in ('401K %','Dental PDO')
```

Comment: @sripriya please learn some basics in sql i think are you new to SQL